# $Z(Q_{12})$ center of quaternion and conjugacy classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was trying to calculate the conjugacy classes of $Q_{12}$ quaternion of order 12 and I found that the identity is the only element with conjugacy class consists of one element. Therefore, the center of $Q_{12}$ is trivial. Is my calculation correct?

Thanks

Comment: I found conjugate classes of orders 1,2,3,6. I guess Orbit stabilizer theorem justifies my answer but still not sure.